# DTFT of $ f[k] = 3^k u(-k-1)$

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, z-transform, dtft

> Find the Discrete-time Fourier transform of $ f[k] = 3^k u(-k-1)$
>   (then sketch it and find its magnitude & angle).

It doesn't fit any templates on the Fourier table, and I don't see how one could re-arrange this expression to solve it. So, how?

Also for $\mathcal Z$-transform, how does one solve:

> you have $\displaystyle H(z) = \frac{1}{1 - \frac 12 z^{-1}}$
>   and input to that is $f[k] = 2^k$

How do you find $y(t)$?

The general formula of $\mathcal Z$-transform is:

$$F(z) = \sum_{k=\infty}^{0} f[k] z^{-k}$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [z-transform of $2^k$](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/40676/z-transform-of-2k)

Comment: @msm Except that doesn't have an answer either. I can't close a question as duplicate if the "duplicate" is not answered (well, I can, I just think it's nonsensical).

Comment: You are right @PeterK. I should have flagged the original question for lack of context as well. It seems qualified for closure.

Comment: @msm what lack of context? you simply chose to ignore my last question. Please don't offer that kind of "help" if you fail to follow up with a response.